# media files aren't served to template in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-file-upload, django-media

I trying to serve media files to the template but make them inaccessible from url, 
and the opposite is happening 
 when i do: http://localhost:8000/media/210000002A.tif

I get prompted to download the files so it is being served when accessing from the address bar 
 but in the template I have: 
    `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}210000002A.tif"/>`
and it is not working

my dir contains 
-project 
-app 
-media 
-static 
-template

and i have this is my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and this in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT:
 
the problem was the .tif extension i just used jpg and it works .. !